# After Login Username gets displayed on dashboard in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

In C# Application I want to set/Show username(logged In) in my dashboard form, So how do I do it. Thanks in Advance.
Following is my Code.

```
con.dataGet("Select * from [User] Where UserName = '"+txtUserName.Text+"' AND Password = '"+txtPassword.Text+"'");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.Hide();
            frmMain frm = new frmMain();
            frm.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username And Password..!", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Please help me.
Regards,
Dharamraj

Comment: I think you could improve your question by providing more context. For example is this a WPF application or is it something else? Also, identifier that are meaningful help understanding your code better. Example: what does `con.sda` stand for? Identifiers such as `Fill` or `dataGet` are better. - Separate from that it appears as if you are storing passwords directly in the database. Is this homework for school or uni?

Comment: **Some tips to help you get an answer:**
1. Explain what type of app it is (e.g. Windows Forms?)
2. Provide more context about your application, and what your dashboard (form) looks like.
**Some warnings about your code** (in case it is anything more than a coding exercise or tutorial):
1. Looks like it will be vulnerable to SQL injection exploits.
2. Looks like it is storing the password in cleartext. It should hash passwords.

Comment: [please take a look at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)
try to use always Stored Procedure to get data from the DB. your requirement is simply to display the value where you want . you just bind the value of the label.

Comment: 1.Windows form    2. frmMain

Comment: My concern is that after login I want to display Username on my other forms which is created by me

Comment: @Manfred my concern is that I want to display username on other forms/page after sucessful login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, and most important, **don't ever use concatenated SQL queries** because you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameters to pass the values into the SQL command.
An example of how to use them: [SqlCommand Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Second to get the data you need, you just simply use the `dt` variable you fill with information from the db.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     //getting the value from the DataTable
     var userName = dt.Rows[0]["UserName_Column"];
     //at this point you have the user name
     //also a good idea is to store the user id, if available

     this.Hide();
     frmMain frm = new frmMain();
     frm.Show();
}
```

Comment: Your answer sure help me but I want to display it on another form.  My startup page is login and after sucessful login its redirected to frmMain form. So I want to display Username on frmMain page. So I need your help. So sir please help

Comment: You can use the next form constructor to pass that value, or you can create a static class or property in the main class you use as startup and set that class/property here, after you get the value.